# INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:

Tags: tomcat, hadoop, oozie

I am new by to Oozie , faced many problem in building oozie-4.0.1 with hadoop-2.2.0 in ubuntu. now it is build with the help this [link](http://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-tried-installing-oozie-4-0-0-with-apache-hadoop-2-2-0-and-java1-7-0_45-on-ubuntu). I am facing now new problem in starting oozie using command `bin/oozied.sh run`. the error traced displays:  `INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:`  with below details

**Error:**

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/java/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1653)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1682)
    at sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:274)
    at sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:263)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.AppContext.initMainAppContext(AppContext.java:263)
    at sun.awt.AppContext.access$400(AppContext.java:133)
    at sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:318)
    at sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:301)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.AppContext.getAppContext(AppContext.java:300)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:154)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(ImageIO.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.lifecycleEvent(JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
    ... 6 more
```

I am struggling it lot, cannot find any thread related to this error. 
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot searching above error , didnt get right one, but found the cause for error  `Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/java/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` that was due to Ubuntu 64 bit with 32 bit jdk 7. then i re install  Ubuntu 32 bit and followed the steps on the link it works for me. Thanks...